# Render object in reactjs

Tags: arrays, json, rest, reactjs

I have symfony rest api and I'm writing some frontend for this (1st time using react). So, here is my index.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visits: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const url = 'http://localhost/app.php/api/visits?from=2017-05-05&to=2017-05-08';
        axios.get(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(
                visits => this.setState({visits})
            ).catch(err => err)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ul>
                    {this.state.visits.map((visit, index) => <li key={index}>{visit}</li>)}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, app);
```

Response from api looks like:

```
{
    "2017-05-05":  2,
    "2017-05-06":  8,
    "2017-05-07": 10,
    "2017-05-08":  1,
}
```

How can i iterate through that and print it to the screen?
Now i don't get any errors, just getting response from server but don't have anything on the screen.

Greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not any `array`, its a `object` so directly `map` will not work on that. First we need to use `Object.keys()` to get all the keys in an `array` then use `map` on that.

Like this:

```
render() {
    let visits = this.state.visits;
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {Object.keys(visits).map((visit, index) => <li key={index}>{visit} : {visits[visit]}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`Object.keys`: will return an `array` of all the keys of that `object`.

Check the working snippet:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            visits: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
           visits: {
              "2017-05-05":2,
              "2017-05-06":8,
              "2017-05-07":10,
              "2017-05-08":1
            }
        })        
    }

    render() {
      let visits = this.state.visits;
      return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {Object.keys(visits).map((visit, index) => <li key={index}>{visit} : {visits[visit]}</li>)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: Yeah, my bad about this array. I made some changes with request (changed axios to fetch) and it's working with your code, thanks! :)

Comment: You can also use `Object.entries`, which returns a list of `[key, value]`: `Object.entries(visits).map(([visit, n], index) => <li key={index}>{visit} : {n}</li>)`

Comment: I  have one more problem. I'm getting data from 3 endpoints (visits, entrances and visitors). Responses are looking same (this same date but other number). How can I map this to render it in one table? Create other function which will merge that to one object?